# Translate sql query to ActiveRecord Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How i write this query on rails terminal?

```
select
    month(created_at) as 'mês',
    sum(points) as 'total de pontos',
    count(*) as 'operações',
    avg(points) as 'média'
from
    cashmilhas_07_16.operations
where
    operation_type = 1
    and created_at >= '2018-01-01'
group by
    year(created_at),
    month(created_at)
```

Comment: What is your model name? Also it is very easy to write in AR.

Comment: model is Operation

Comment: please read this https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html , you will be able to write it by yourself. If again got stuck, then show the AR query tried..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is:

```
Operation.find_by_sql [
  'select
      month(created_at) as "mês",
      sum(points) as "total de pontos",
      count(*) as "operações",
      avg(points) as "média"
    from cashmilhas_07_16.operations
    where operation_type = :type and created_at >= :date
    group by year(created_at), month(created_at)',
  { type: 1, date: '2018-01-01' }
]
```

Or:

```
Operation.where("operation_type = :type and created_at >= :date", { type: 1, date: '2018-01-01' })
         .select('month(created_at) as "mês", sum(points) as "total de pontos", count(*) as "operações", avg(points) as "média"')
         .group("year(created_at), month(created_at)")
```

Both methods are well described in [Rails API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html)

Comment: The return is empty but if I put this query: 

Operation.where("operation_type = :type and created_at >= :date", { type: 1, date: '2018-01-01' }).count

Have the return

Comment: What about 1st query?

Comment: Sorry, but I think your original query returns empty result. Try to run that query in db console (whatever you use, mysql or postgres)

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

sql = "SELECT MONTH(created_at) as 'mês', sum(points) as 'total de pontos',count(*) as 'operações', avg(points) as 'média', avg(cost) as 'custo médio', avg(cost) * (sum(points)/10000) as 'gasto total' FROM operations where operation_type = 2 AND source_target_id = 1 AND created_at >= '2018-01-01' GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at);"

results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)

results.rows